# When will the new thresholds kick in ?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Does anyone know when the new threshold will kick in ? for example, when we're out of beta, you can't vote to close/reopen unless you have 3000 rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's already kicked in! For instance, access to moderator tools needs a rep of 10,000. I can't access it anymore. In beta, I could; since the threshold was 3,000 (or 2,000. I don't recall exactly).

Comment: groan. ok. I hope that we have moderator elections soon then, so we can get more moderators in place.

Comment: But shiva was able to vote to close with rep < 3000

Comment: @Suresh: I didn't know we would have "moderator elections." I should start a campaign ;) Joking aside, I don't know how Shiva voted to close. Maybe there was a glitch in the system?

Comment: @Suresh: I think he voted before the new system kicked in. Now we have only 10 users who can vote to close questions, but hopefully that will suffice for now.

Comment: I think moderator elections are a month away or so. they are still working out the kinks in the new voting system I think.

Comment: @Suresh: Yeah, they seem to have migrated from “one user, one vote” system to “one user, three votes” in 2010 SO mod-election (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-begins/)

Answer (score 3):

I think that the new thresholds are already in effect.  For example, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions says that voting to close requires 3000 reputation points.